# configuring the PLL SX1781 in python

Tags: python, spi

i hope someone con help me on this.
I need to configure the registers of a specific PLL, the SX1781, using python programming language. I need to do that via SPI. I connected the PLL with my raspberry (connected the SPI pins) and tried to configure its registers with this code that i created:

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 1)

RegNDivMsb = spi.xfer2([0x01])    # address register
RegNDivMsb = spi.xfer2([0x02])     # value to write on register

RegNDivLsb = spi.xfer2([0x00])
RegNDivLsb = spi.xfer2([0x68])

RegRDiv = spi.xfer2([0x02])
RegRDiv = spi.xfer2([0x33])

RegGenCtrl = spi.xfer2([0x03])
RegGenCtrl = spi.xfer2([0x04])
```

I tried to implement in with idle (launched with sudo idle so i can have root permissions) and also installed the  Python Dev package. I want to modify the registers with the second value that i try to send, but it doesn't. Can someone give me a hand please?